# Use display_url from Twitter json feed

Tags: php, json, twitter, rss

I'm running into an issue that I'm hoping is reasonably straight forward as far as a solution. I'm using Thomas Yung's Twitter JSON to RSS https://github.com/thomasyung/twitter-json-to-rss and I've run into an issue with trying to get the script to actually output the display_url variable. I'm not a PHP wiz by any stretch, but it seems reasonably simple how they are accessing the various information points in twitter_json_to_rss.php starting at line 85.

```
$title= htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars_decode($line->user->name.": ".strip_tags($line->text)));
$description= htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags($line->text)));
$url = htmlspecialchars("https://twitter.com/".$line->user->screen_name."/statuses/".$line->id_str);;
$image = (strlen($line->entities->media[0]->media_url)>0) ? htmlspecialchars($line->entities->media[0]->media_url) : null;
$created_at = rfc822Date($line->created_at);
```

Now it seems reasonably straightforward how the variables are being called based on the structure of the json output I included below. If I want to output the display_url should be as simple as calling $line->entities->urls->display_url but that just doesn't seem to be working. Is there something I'm missing here? It seems I can't access anything from the entities section, but I can pull in the majority of the other variables available in the JSON. Is there some things I'm not allowed to access from the Twitter API or something like that? I'm just at a loss as to why it's not working.

```
 {
  "created_at":"Sun Mar 16 19:57:47 +0000 2014",
  "id":445287835055439872,
  "id_str":"445287835055439872",
  "text":"93% of Crimeans vote to join Russia, exit polls show http:\/\/t.co\/57teqvKOmB",
  "source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.socialflow.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eSocialFlow\u003c\/a\u003e",
  "truncated":false,
  "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id":null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
  "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
  "user":{
     "id":972651,
     "id_str":"972651",
     "name":"Mashable",
     "screen_name":"mashable",
     "location":"",
     "description":"News, resources, inspiration and fun for the connected generation. Tweets by @mashable staff.",
     "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/1Gm8aVACKn",
     "entities":{
        "url":{
           "urls":[
              {
                 "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/1Gm8aVACKn",
                 "expanded_url":"http:\/\/mashable.com",
                 "display_url":"mashable.com",
                 "indices":[
                    0,
                    22
                 ]
              }
           ]
        },
        "description":{
           "urls":[

           ]
        }
     },
     "protected":false,
     "followers_count":3870836,
     "friends_count":2740,
     "listed_count":112874,
     "created_at":"Mon Mar 12 01:28:01 +0000 2007",
     "favourites_count":193,
     "utc_offset":-14400,
     "time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
     "geo_enabled":false,
     "verified":true,
     "statuses_count":98940,
     "lang":"en",
     "contributors_enabled":false,
     "is_translator":false,
     "is_translation_enabled":true,
     "profile_background_color":"00AEEF",
     "profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/705312036\/bf7ca2a3f077d7e57b12a5ea4f1db268.png",
     "profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/705312036\/bf7ca2a3f077d7e57b12a5ea4f1db268.png",
     "profile_background_tile":false,
     "profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3690637553\/5c348fee8afbcefa1978004a864a51ce_normal.png",
     "profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3690637553\/5c348fee8afbcefa1978004a864a51ce_normal.png",
     "profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/972651\/1369156394",
     "profile_link_color":"00AEEF",
     "profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF",
     "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"88DBF4",
     "profile_text_color":"3B3B3B",
     "profile_use_background_image":false,
     "default_profile":false,
     "default_profile_image":false,
     "following":false,
     "follow_request_sent":false,
     "notifications":false
  },
  "geo":null,
  "coordinates":null,
  "place":null,
  "contributors":null,
  "retweet_count":74,
  "favorite_count":20,
  "entities":{
     "hashtags":[

     ],
     "symbols":[

     ],
     "urls":[
        {
           "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/57teqvKOmB",
           "expanded_url":"http:\/\/on.mash.to\/1gwwY3W",
           "display_url":"on.mash.to\/1gwwY3W",
           "indices":[
              53,
              75
           ]
        }
     ],
     "user_mentions":[

     ]
  },
  "favorited":false,
  "retweeted":false,
  "possibly_sensitive":false,
  "lang":"en"
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `urls` seems to be an array. Try this -

```
$line->entities->urls[0]->display_url
```